# Why can't I find certain music videos on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I am from India and I don't know if there's the region or country problem but I cannot find videos such as "No Favors - Big Sean feat. Eminem" or "Campaign Speech - Eminem"?

What could be the possible reason?

A side question to Eminem followers: I found Campaign Speech on this new channel "EminemMusic". Is this a new channel of Eminem because I don't feel so? Why didn't he upload it to his "EminemVevo"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue related to your physical location, because the two Eminem music videos that you mentioned in your question show in the search results of YouTube in my computer. You can verify this for yourself by installing Tor Browser Bundle and searching for the same two music videos in Tor browser.

From [What is Tor Browser?](https://web.archive.org/web/20170322170732/https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) at the official Tor website:

> Tor Browser protects you by bouncing your communications around a distributed network of relays run by volunteers all around the world: it prevents somebody watching your Internet connection from learning what sites you visit, it prevents the sites you visit from learning your physical location, and it lets you access sites which are blocked.

Beyond this the question of why certain music videos are not uploaded to certain websites is primarily opinion-based, therefore it is not possible to answer this part of your question accurately.

Comment: Or I can just use a simple VPN or proxy to do the same! Alright, thanks!